# getting yarn-site.xml error while configuring hadoop namenode on mac os

Tags: java, xml, macos, hadoop

I am trying to configure my mac as a hadoop namenode. After typing this command:

```
bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

I get this error:

```
[Fatal Error] yarn-site.xml:3:4: Comment must start with "<!--".
15/12/28 20:32:06 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf yarn-site.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Library/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml; 
lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 4; Comment must start with "<!--".
```

But the yarn-site.xml file has that comment. Here is the content of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-—
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License”);
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small mistake here:

```
<!-—
```

This should be (Observe the second '-'. You need to replace "—" with "-"):

```
<!--
```

So the corrected document is (I validated it using XMLValidator: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License?);
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But now I got a different error,
after putting command:

    $ sbin/start-dfs.sh

I get this error
    16/01/29 22:59:59 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-  hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable...